# Ant Design Date range Picker showing only one month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AJlJ.png)

As per the documentation the date range picker should have two months defined in calendar respectively, but the calendar is showing only one month.

After going through the documentation I changed the value from storing single value to an array

```
here is my code snippet:
<RangePicker
                format={"YYYY-MM-DD"}
                size="small"
                value={[
                  dayjs(globalDates?.startDate, "YYYY-MM-DD"),
                  dayjs(globalDates?.endDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")
                ]}
                name="startDate"
                picker="day"
                allowClear={false}
                style={styles?.rangePickerStyles}
                className="h-12 w-full"
                popupStyle={{ zIndex: 9999 }}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
              />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the ant design documentation **[HERE](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/edit/master/components/date-picker/demo/range-picker.tsx)**. you can see all the types of the date picker that there are, I suggest you have a look at this one (*based on the image that you presented*)

```
<RangePicker picker="week" />
```

You can then append all the other component props or even event handlers as use it as you wish.

---

Moreover, if you then check this code, yet again from the official documentation **[HERE](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/edit/master/components/date-picker/demo/format.tsx)**.
[image]

You can then see how to add the default values: